# Linux: how to get all login logs from my system

Tags: linux, logs, login

I want to know all the times a user logs since last year into my system?
I used `last` command but it is not useful.

Comment: welcome to Stack Exchange! please remember that we're all volunteers here. as such, we expect that you've done some basic research. it looks like you have a start - since you mention trying the `last` command - but you should be doing more research than that, and in any case, you haven't actually specified _why_ the `last` command isn't useful. also, define "logged in". do you want to track console logins? SSH logins? Emacs forbid, `telnet` logins? or just anything authenticating with PAM? be _specific_.

Answer (score 14):

The login logs on redhat-style linux are called `wtmp` (`man wtmp`), stored in `/var/log/` by default, and you can retrieve them using `utmpdump` (on RHEL6).

```
[root@server ~]# utmpdump /var/log/wtmp* | awk '$4~"root" {print}'
Utmp dump of /var/log/wtmp
[7] [01320] [ts/0] [root    ] [pts/0       ] [192.168.1.101       ] [192.168.1.101  ] [Tue Sep 24 00:31:47 2013 UTC]
[7] [01817] [ts/3] [root    ] [pts/3       ] [192.168.1.101       ] [192.168.1.101  ] [Tue Sep 24 00:38:22 2013 UTC]
[7] [01690] [ts/0] [root    ] [pts/0       ] [192.168.1.101       ] [192.168.1.101  ] [Tue Sep 24 00:59:04 2013 UTC]
[7] [23641] [ts/0] [root    ] [pts/0       ] [192.168.1.101       ] [192.168.1.101  ] [Wed Sep 25 19:12:44 2013 UTC]
[7] [03020] [ts/0] [root    ] [pts/0       ] [192.168.1.100       ] [192.168.1.100  ] [Fri Sep 27 21:33:40 2013 UTC]
...
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems `last` can be used to achieve what you are trying to do. You need to append the date to the last command to extract the information.

```
last | while read line; do date=`date -d "$(echo $line | awk '{ print $5" "$6" "$7 }')" +%s`; [[ $date -ge `date -d "Aug 25 00:00" +%s` && $date -le `date -d "Aug 28 00:00" +%s` ]] && echo $line; done
```

However, if you are concerned with finding information about a particular user, you can modify the last command as `last username` and then pipe the `while` loop to it. It would give you the information of a particular user's login information for the last one year.

I tested the above command and it works perfectly fine in my system. I took the above command from [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/305738/how-do-i-extract-login-history).

You can change the date in the command to suit your requirements.